# Update state from outside of components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, jwt, state

[This is a similar question but it provided solution for the specific issue of OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37513440/set-react-component-state-from-outside-of-component)

I am trying to implement authentication in my React app using `JWT`. After logging in, server sends `access token` and `refresh token`. Access token expires shorty within an hour while refresh token is persistant for a year. Both are stored in `localStorage`.

I am using `axios` to make requests to server. I have created a file `api.js` that creates an `axiosInstance` which sets up baseURL for requests. This file exports this axios instance and every other component/ file that wants to use axios, imports it from this file - api.js. I have also set up an `axios interceptor` in the same file that will modify each request before sending it. It will basically add access token in `authorization` header if token has not expired, otherwise it will use refresh token to get new access token.

Now I have a `TokenProvider` Context that basically wraps whole app and it gives you token and a method to update this given token as well as the one in localstorage `(useToken)`.

After i get the access token from the server with the help of refresh token, i want to update it in localstorage as well as the token that TokenProvider provides. I tried importing useToken from TokenProvider in api.js but React won't allow to use hooks in functions that are not components.

> React Hook "useToken" is called in function "{functionName}" that is
> neither a React function component nor a custom React Hook function.
> React component names must start with an uppercase letter.

How should i go about implementing this functionality to update TokenProvider's token? Should i listen for events in TokenProvider that are trigged when localStorage updates or shoudl i try to convert api.js into some type of React component?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [useContext inside axios interceptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64296505/usecontext-inside-axios-interceptor)

Comment: @Mario Petrovic Thanks but it seems to solve a slightly different problem

Answer (score 0):

use forwardRef , read the docs [here](https://fr.reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html)
Create function inside the components that call for your setStateName(),
and call it from the ref of your components